# Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller (UINavigationController) while a presentation or dismiss is in progress

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, nsnotification

I have 2 view controllers. `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`. The second is presented through `presentViewController...`

Both are listening to a notification:

**FirstViewController.m**

```
- (void)facebookUpdated:(NSNotification *)notification {

    if (![[FacebookHelper sharedInstance] isLoggedIn]) {

        [self.addReminderTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(1, 2)] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
}
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
- (void)facebookUpdated:(NSNotification *)notification {

    if (![[FacebookHelper sharedInstance] isLoggedIn]) {

        // The user decided not to log in

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        }];
    }
}
```

The `SecondViewController` is dismissed and the table in `FirstViewController` is reloaded. But I'm getting this warning which I don't like

> Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller
>    while a presentation or dismiss is
>   in progress!

And I'm really not sure why I'm getting it. I'm sure there is no other dismissal in progress. I'm not sure what a presentation in progress means?

Answer (score 0):

This warning can happen if the `SecondViewController` is dismissed with a call to `(void)facebookUpdated:(NSNotification *)notification` before the animation to make it appear in the first place has finished.

You can:

1. Ignore the warning
2. Avoid it by not animating the display of SecondViewController if it is likely to be dismissed right away.
3. Avoid it while still allowing animation by setting a callback on the initial view controller animation that calls a function on the second view controller telling it that the animation has finished. Then you can check for this property in `(void)facebookUpdated:(NSNotification *)notification` before calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated`, and, if the load hasn't finish, set another flag to have the original animation callback function  call `dismissViewControllerAnimated`. *(This is probably the most correct solution, but is also the most complicated.)*